# How to get return value from a function called which executes in another thread in TBB?

Tags: c++, multithreading, return-value, function-pointers, tbb

In the code:

```
    #include <tbb/tbb.h>

    int GetSomething()
    {
        int something;
        // do something
        return something;
    }

    // ...
    tbb::tbb_thread(GetSomething, NULL);
    // ...
```

Here `GetSomething()` was called in another thread via its pointer. But can we get return value from `GetSomething()`? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are bound C++03 and tbb you have to use Outputarguments, which means that you have to rewrite your function.

e.g.:

```
void GetSomething(int* out_ptr);

int var = 23;

tbb::tbb:thread(GetSomething, &var); // pay attention that this doesn't run of scope
```

or with `boost::ref` you can do this:

```
void GetSomething(int& out);

int var = 23;
tbb::tbb_thread(GetSomething, boost::ref(var)); // pay attention here, too
```

If you can use C++11 the task is simplified by using `futures`:

e.g.:

```
std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, GetSomething);

....

// later

int result = fut.get();
```

Here you don't have to rewrite anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pass by reference to get value from thread

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

void GetSomething(int *result)
{

    result= // do something
}

// ...
int result;
tbb::tbb_thread(GetSomething, &result);
tbb.join();
//use result as you like
```

Comment: the change you made invalidated your code, `std::ref` creates a `std::reference_wrapper` which is not equal to `&var` which returns the address of your variable. beside that, `std::ref` is C++11, which would call futures on the plan.