# TBB / Threading Building Blocks: Getting return value from a Task

Tags: multithreading, task, block, tbb, building

this question is similar to [How to get return value from a function called which executes in another thread in TBB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871836/how-to-get-return-value-from-a-function-called-which-executes-in-another-thread) but I am working with tasks.

I have the following code:

```
vector<vector<int> > all;
for(h=0; h<100;h++){
    vector<int> vector1= Node(anotherVector[h], value - 1, anotherVector[h].size()); 
    for (unsigned int u = 0; u < vector1.size(); u++) {
        all[h].push_back(vector1[u]);
    }
}
```

"vector1" saves the result of the recursive call from Node.
I want TBB to call the Node parallel. And then to use "vector1" to push it to "all".
My problem is that if I am trying to use tasks, I need to return a Task object from Node in order to use spawn_and_wait_for_all(taskobjectlist here).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question because as it is stated it makes less sense to me. So, a few notes why.

`tbb::task` is a low-level interface which is not generally recommended for usage unless you know what you are doing. For example, `spawn_and_wait_for_all(task_list)` is inefficient for long lists (>10). Recursive parallelism like divide and conquire, and especially a work with vectors, can be implemented using `tbb::parallel_reduce` or if you want use just tasks, take a look at `tbb::task_group` or `tbb::parallel_invoke`.
Please also note that `std:vector` does not allow performing safe concurrent `push_back()` simultaneously from different tasks, it is not thread-safe. Instead, you can try `tbb::concurrent_vector<>` but I'd rather recommend to try `tbb::parallel_reduce` or `tbb::combinable` first.

Comment: Hi Anton,
thanks for the advice. I looked a bit further into this but can´t really find something that is working.
For example when I use task_groups, the code could be like:

g->run(Node(anotherVector[h], value - 1, anotherVector[h].size()));
g->wait();
I have no option to get the returned result of that task.

Comment: A task can carry a reference to the output structure. No need to return something like in functional programming.

Comment: Where can I read more about this? Is there an example somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: I need a variable that only the upper task / thread can access, not a single global variable...

Comment: well.. You can read C++ language reference/books for how to create classes with your variables. Or using new C++ standard (2011), you can use lambda functions (which result in the same auto-generated class) and capture the pointer/reference to your output structure.